# converting string to datetime without success in python

Tags: python, string, datetime, format

so I am reading the datetime from a file (but it is reading it as a string) and then converting it to a datetime format using this simple code

```
 last_update_str = flast.readlines()[-1].strip()
 dateformat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
 last_update = time.strptime(last_update_str,dateformat)
 next_run_date = last_update - timedelta(days=2)
```

and I am getting this error:

raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data "'2023-12-03 00:00'" does not match format '%YYYY-%mm-%dd %HH:%MM'

input file has only this line:

'2023-12-03 00:00'

can anyone please help, it seems like a minor issue but have taken me more than a day and I am still not able to fix it.
TIA

Comment: What are the contents of `last_update_str` when that exception is raised?

Comment: last_update_str is:'2023-12-03 00:00'

Comment: maybe you have a caridge return  in your string try `.rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `strptime` wrong way,
It accepts as:

- `%Y`: Year with century as a decimal number.
- `%m`: Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%d`: Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%H`: Hour (00 to 23).
- `%M`: Minute (00 to 59).

So, the proper way to do this is using:

```py
last_update = time.strptime(last_update_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: again same error:     raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data "'2023-12-03 00:00'" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

Comment: I got it there is `'` in your string see after `"` try removing single `'`, and then run.
The input must be like `"2023-12-03 00:00"`, not like `"'2023-12-03 00:00'"`.

Comment: use this `last_update_str = last_update_str.strip("'")`

Comment: that fixed the issue... Thanks Anurag.. but now my output is : last update time is:time.struct_time(tm_year=2023, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=337, tm_isdst=-1)...

Comment: fixed it... I was using time.strptime instead of datetime.strptime...

Comment: **Happy to help!!**

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the data has a single quotation mark `'` at the beginning and at the end. To remove these characters, use the `strip` function.

Also, if the file has only one line, why do you use readlines? It's enough to use the `readline` function (and `strip`).

About the library, if you use the time library you can't do operations between a `datetime` object and a `time` object, they are two different types. I suggest `datetime` because it fits this situation perfectly.

So my solution is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# supposing the contents of the file are:
# '2023-12-03 00:00'
with open('./my_file', 'r') as f:
    # save date and remove '
    last_update_str = f.readline().strip("'")

date_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
last_update = datetime.strptime(last_update_str, date_format)
next_run_date = last_update - timedelta(days=2)
```

If you want to use `strptime` from the `time` library, you have to convert it to a `datetime` object before doing the difference operation (no sense in my opinion):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# supposing the contents of the file are:
# '2023-12-03 00:00'
with open('./my_file', 'r') as f:
    # save date and remove '
    last_update_str = f.readline().strip("'")

date_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
last_update = time.strptime(last_update_str, date_format)
last_update = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(last_update))
next_run_date = last_update - timedelta(days=2)
```

The `mktime` function takes as argument the return value of `strptime` and converts it to a `datetime` object ([official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime)).